# ImmutableJS updates the third argument during mapping?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have an Immutable List and I run a `map`. The third argument is the list itself (`iter`), but it seems like it does not reference the original one but updates it for elements it had already processed.

```
Immutable.fromJS([1, 2]).map((e, i, l) => console.log(l.toJS()))
```

Prints:

```
[1, 2]
[undefined, 2]
```

For the first element it prints the original list, but for the second one the list seems changed.

I'd expect the third argument to always reference the *original* list and not a partially updated one.

I'm sure I'm just missing a minor point here, but I can't see why it's not the case.

```
Immutable.version
"4.0.0-rc.12"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a performance optimization feature.

For performance reasons a mutable list is created, and that's also what is passed in the mapping loop, not the original. You'll have to hold on to the original instance yourself.

https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js/blob/master/src/List.js#L176

Comment: Doesn't that make the third argument worse than useless? I can't trust it to be the original structure, and it invites people to reuse the last results which is just plain wrong.

Comment: From a practical standpoint, nothing is preventing you from keeping a reference to the original, and there is no efficient way to keep track of 'what was already mapped'. This of course implies an in-order iteration, which makes the map() operation less pure conceptually. But this is javascript, not haskell :)